# Tracking ONE person in a scene with many people

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, motion-detection

I need to identify and track one person in a video scene which may contain other objects/people.

Currently, using OpenCV, I can track all people in the frame. (my code is based on the OpenCV examples using Haar CascadeClassifiers)

I have few images of the person I want to track.
My question is two fold:

1. How can I identify the person I want to track in the frame?
2. How can I track only this person in the frame and not others?

If I use some face tracking method, all people are identified and all faces are tracked.
I do not want this to happen.

Somewhat related is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442963/how-to-track-one-person-with-kinect-trackingid) for kinect. I want to use a web camera and OpenCV to be able to do this task.

Thanks,
Akshay

PS: Pythonic solution will simplify my task, but any solution/direction towards a solution is also greatly appreciated :)

Comment: why is face tracking not ok? if you track all people, your single person is tracked too, right? so you should explain why that's not ok (performance issues? data privacy issues?). what kind of input images do you have (bird's-eye-view? overhead? front?) (maybe some sample images or videos would be great). Detection/Classification (identify your target person) and tracking that object can be quite different topics, too.

Comment: @Micka I agree that detection & tracking are quite different. Sorry I missed giving the big picture. This "task" is a part of a robotics experiment where, the robot is expected to track the person and only that person. Hence using OpenCV if I am able to identify the person, and track him, I can use this as input to the robot to do the tracking. Hope it helps?

Comment: @GilLevi I am trying that out now. I saw that last night after posting the question. I will probably reply after I see the out come. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I was able to get partial success using face recognition as suggested by @GilLevi. The results are not as good. I will post an update if I manage to get something better.